# Recyclerview measure is not updated correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have `RecyclerView` with its parent which is part of `NestedScrollView`. Its universal `NestedScrollView` because this `NestedScrollView` can have any type of `ViewGroup` inside it. But this specific component I'm using is using `RecyclerView` in it. `NestedScrollView` has limit to what is its maximum height on display which can be setup in code.

Issue is that if I populate my `RecyclerView`, its height is not corresponding with number of items in it. It returns height of roughly single item in it. I need to return height of entire `RecyclerView` content so `NestedScrollView` can stretch its height based on content inside `RecyclerView` (maybe limit it to maxHeight set in `NestedScrollView` if `RecyclerView` content is higher).

Here is layout which is fed to `NestedScrollView` from this particular component:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:background="@color/white_background">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.project.components.loading_indicator.LoadingIndicator
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my NestedScrollView:

```
class ScrollViewWithMaxHeight: NestedScrollView{
    companion object {
        var WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE = -1
    }
    
    private var maxHeight = WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}

    var onHeightChangeListener: ((Int)->Unit)? = null
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        var measuredHeight = heightMeasureSpec
        val currHeight = getCurrContentHeight()
        try {
            val heightSize: Int
            App.log("ScrollViewWithMaxHeight: onMeasure curr_height: $currHeight, max: $maxHeight")
            if (maxHeight != WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE && currHeight > maxHeight) {
                heightSize = maxHeight
            } else {
                heightSize = currHeight
            }
            measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
            layoutParams.height = heightSize
            onHeightChangeListener?.invoke(heightSize)
        } catch (_: Exception) { } finally {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, measuredHeight)
        }
    }

    private fun getCurrContentHeight(): Int{
        var height = 0
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            val h = child.measuredHeight
            App.log("ScrollViewWithMaxHeight: getCurrChildHeight: $h, count: $childCount")
            if (h > height) height = h
        }

        return height
    }

    fun setOnDynamicHeightChangeListener(l: (Int)->Unit){
        onHeightChangeListener = l
    }

    fun setMaxHeight(maxHeight: Int) {
        this.maxHeight = maxHeight
    }
}
```

`getCurrContentHeight()` should be called every time as some children within `NestedScrollView` change their content (height) so `NestedScrollView` height can be adjusted on fly accordingly.

But even after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` within component with `RecyclerView`, height of `RecyclerView` is simply too small to what its content is.

Even if after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` I call

```
list.apply {
    requestLayout()
    invalidate()
}
```

It is still returning `list.measuredHeight` 86 pixels which is height of single item.